# Is there online editor for apple scripts that I can practice on?

Tags: applescript, editor

I'm new with apple scripts and yet don't have a MAC to work on, learn and practice.
Is there any online web editor that simulates mac and apple scripts that can be written there or any editor which can be downloaded to Windows 10 and simulate it?

I tried to look on the network for this kind of editor.

N/A

N/A

Comment: Nope. Best option would be to blag a free/cheap old Mac Mini: an early Core 2 Duo that runs 10.11 El Capitan will do (<$50 on eBay). Not worth a big spend, TBH; with Shortcuts due on macOS next year, AppleScript’s long-term future is hazy at best.

Comment: I'd look into Hammerspoon.  It's a lot more capable than AppleScript, and it is scripted in a language called Lua that takes approximately 8 minutes to learn (I'm being facetious, but it's a very unambiguous language, great for newbies, and used for other things, notably by gamers for games or whatever, but is the scripting language of some specific applications, such as VLC.)

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript is tied to Mac OS. You can't run it on any other platform.

So it's not the editor you need (you can write AppleScript in any text editor on any platform), rather you need the runtime environment - which is Mac OS, and whatever Mac applications you seek to automate.

I've heard it's [possible to run Mac OS in a virtual machine](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-run-a-mac-os-in-windows-virtual-machine), which could be a solution if you absolutely must use Windows.